# Bracket completion with correct tab and insert placement

Tags: autocompletion

I'm looking for a plugin that will autocomplete closing brackets for me. Furthermore, I'd like it to space and tab the inner block automatically.

I've tried a number of them where if I'm typing python for example, I'll get into situations like this (* represents my cursor):

```
def myFunc(){
*}
```

So I get the autocomplete on the `}`, but it 1) doesnt indent for me and 2) leaves the closing bracket on the same line. Instead, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
def myFunc(){
    *
}
```

Where as soon as I hit enter within the `{}` it will correctly indent for me and shift the closing bracket 2 lines down. This is the case in most languages I use (javascript, CSS etc)

Are there any plugins that can do this?

Comment: That feature is available in *every* "autoclosing" plugin on vim.org.

Comment: Quick search for ["bracket" on VimAwsome](http://vimawesome.com/?q=bracket)

Answer (score 3):

[lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/) does it indirectly.

When it detects you hit `<CR>` within a pair of `{}`, it will insert everything that is required. By default, it'll just insert `{}`. You'll have to use `-nl` option of `:Brackets` to force the newline every time (I went back from this configuration)

It's currently defined only for curly brackets, if you want it for other kind of bracket-pairs, you'll have to adapt this snippet of viml:

```
if lh#option#get('cb_newline_within_empty_brackets', 1)
  call lh#brackets#enrich_imap('<cr>',
        \ {'condition': 'getline(".")[col(".")-2:col(".")-1]=="{}"',
        \   'action': 'lh#brackets#_add_newline_between_brackets()'},
        \ 0,
        \ '\<cr\>'
        \ )
endif
```

(i.e. change the condition, or use instead `lh#brackets#define_imap()` that takes a list of condition+action)

But, brackets in Python? Really? BTW, this language may incur side effects regarding automatic indentation.

Comment: gah I've been jumping around languages lately and ive got a mix of JS and python in my brain hence the brackets! I'll take a look at that plugin, thanks. Was hoping for something that works out of the box though